# How to frame a regular expression to match any string with operators at the beginning but not in between

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression which can capture all the strings, which has greater than or less than operators at the beginning only.

Ex.below should be matched.">0", "<0", ">12", "<11", ">1222"

These should not be matched. "99<100", "1010>12233"

Am using the regular expression, ***/(<|>)(\d)+/g*** but it is also matching other ones.

Please let me know if this has other solutions, definitely, it has.

Comment: [`\B([<>])(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/wS9lH2/1)? Or at the beginning of the string: `^([<>])(\d+)`?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Does it mean `\B([<>])(\d+)` worked for you? Shall I post?

Comment: I posted as an answer, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
\B([<>])(\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wS9lH2/1)

The `\B` is a non-word boundary matching at any position other than word boundary (between word or non-word characters). `([<>])` matches and captures a `<` or `>`. The `(\d+)` matches and captures one or more digits.

If you need to match at the beginning of the string only, use

```
^([<>])(\d+)
```

The `^` will require the next `<` or `>` to be right at the start of the string.

Comment: ^[<>](\d)+$ this worked for me. which was mentioned by you and i made small change it. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just anchor your regex:

```
/^(<|>)(\d+)/
```